# NullPointerException in while loop when trying to add new Class instances to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, nullpointerexception, instance

The more I google this the more confused I'm getting.

I'm bringing in a list of names of unknown length with some other details in from a CSV which I then need to turn into Person objects and store in a list called people which is the instance variable for the class Club, a list of its members basically.

This is a very simplified version of something more complex I need to do in which I need to while loop through a file creating objects for each line which I then need to add to a list collection.

I keep getting a nullPointerException error when I run my code though and I'm stumped how to avoid it. I'm guessing that my variable p when I create the new object would need to change on each loop but I don't think it's possible to change variables dynamically is it?

Can't think how I can commit the object to the collection with a valid non null reference each time. Would be very grateful for any help. I've tried to cut out all the unnecessary stuff in the code below.

Thank you

```
   //class arraylist instance variable of class "Club"
   private ArrayList<Person> people;

   //class constructor for Club
   public Club()
   {List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();}

   public void readInClubMembers()
   {
      //some variables concerning the file input
      String currentLine;
      String name;
      String ageGroup;
      while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine())
      {
         //some lines bringing in the scanner input from the file
         name = lineScanner.next();
         ageGroup = "young";
         Person p = new Person(); // i guess things are going wrong around here
         people.add(p);
         p.setName(name);
         p.setAgeGroup(ageGroup);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `List<Person>` before `people = …` inside the constructor, otherwise you are declaring a new local variable `people` inside the constructor shadowing the *field* `people` (which is then never used). This leaves the class field uninitialized (`null`) and then causes the NPE.

What you want instead is initializing the field `people`:

```
public Club() {
    // you can also use "this.people = …" to be explicit
    people = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

To show the difference:

```
class Example {
    private int myNumber;

    public Example() {
        myNumber = 42; // sets the field of the class
        int myNumber = 1337; // declares a new local variable shadowing the class field
        myNumber = -13; // accesses the object in the closest scope which is the local variable
        this.myNumber = 0; // explicitly accesses the class field
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ingo. That's got rid of the error I guess it wasn't looping through the variables that was wrong, no wonder I was getting so confused! In the second section though your "to show the difference", are those values arbitrary? Would you mind explaining those 4 lines more? The fourth I can see is the class variable which was never assigned a value but I do not understand the first three or why they have those numbers.

Comment: @berlinhammer The numbers are just arbitrary examples. The point I am trying to make there is for you to see which variable is being affected by the assignment – the class member or the local variable. "Shadowing" is something you want to avoid anyway, but if it happens it is good to know how to adress the object you *want* to adress.